# TestNG: @Test at class level executing all methods

Tags: testng

I have some tests that need to run sequentially, so I added @Test(singleThreaded = true) to their classes.

Works fine, the problem is that with @Test at class level, all methods are executed by TestNG, even if they don't have a @Test annotation, so eventually this causes some time waste when someone from my team wants to disable a test, and as he's not aware of this particularity he only comments the @Test instead of whole method, so later this test that should be disabled end up making the build process fail.

Is there a way to avoid this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

One way is to educate the team :)

You can just put a new annotation on the single test you want to disable i.e.
In the below, test 2 won't run.

```
@Test(singlet..)
public class Testss {


    public void test1(){
        System.out.println("test1");
    }

    @Test(enabled=false)
    public void test2(){
        System.out.println("test2");
    }

    public void test3(){
        System.out.println("test3");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If executing test sequentially is important I would suggest using dependencies or priority instead of relying on execution order and changing the thread count.

```
@Test
public void method1() {
    System.out.println("This is method 1");
}

@Test(dependsOnMethods = { "method1" })
public void method2() {
    System.out.println("This is method 2");
}
```

or

```
@Test(priority = 1)
public void method1() {
    System.out.println("This is method 1");
}

@Test(priority = 2)
public void method2() {
    System.out.println("This is method 2");
}
```

in conjunction with

```
@Test(enabled = false) //do not run this method as a test
```

and/or

```
<suite name="Suite" parallel="classes" thread-count="3">
```